# Are there any problems in probability theory where it cannot be solved or defined with respect to Borel sets but only with Lebesgue measurable sets?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I saw a post here that dealt with an interesting question: [Why do probabilists take random variables to be Borel (and not Lebesgue) measurable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31603/why-do-probabilists-take-random-variables-to-be-borel-and-not-lebesgue-measura). It basically asked why probability theory is defined on Borel-measurable sets. However, I am wondering if there exists any problems where it can only be solved or defined with respect to Lebesgue measure. Are there any trivial examples? Thanks.

Comment: Conceptually Borel sets are "enriched" by allowing arbitrary subsets of measure zero sets to again have measure zero (sometimes called *null sets* despite the chance of confusion), thus giving us the Lebesgue measurable sets.  This is very useful in integration theory, but no so much in real world applications.  So you might be interested in looking into the topics of integration theory where so-called null sets are a helpful addition to Borel measure.

Comment: I know that a lot of papers and books making use of probability theory include discussions or uses of analytic sets (or more extensive collections of sets). Try googling "probability" and "analytic sets". [This 1978 paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102805997) by Steven E. Shreve appears to apply $C$-sets to probability, for example. All $C$-sets are Lebesgue measurable, but there exist Lebesgue measurable sets that are not $C$-sets. (Indeed, there are $2^c$ many Lebesgue measurable sets but only $c=2^{\aleph_0}$ many $C$-sets.)

Comment: In probability theory, I think one should work with Borel measurable functions but not Lebesgue measurable ones, because probability measures are Borel measures but not necessarily absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. And usually in probability theory one should work with not only a probability measure, but a sequence of probability measures. Yes, as @DaveL.Renfro pointed out, one can work with universally measurable things.